# rsyslog to stop forwarding logs if recover/destination server is unavailable

Tags: rsyslog

I'm forwarding the logs with rsyslog (tcp) from 10 servers to a log collector. RHEL 6.9.

If the network between log collector and the servers is down, I'm hitting login issues. 
Known issue: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1250933

I'm checking to see if it is possible to tell rsyslog service to stop forwarding logs if the network is down and resume once the connection is back- using forwarding rules or any other way.

A rule similar to:

```
> $ActionQueueType LinkedList # use asynchronous processing
> $ActionQueueFileName srvrfwd # set file name, also enables disk mode
> $ActionResumeRetryCount -1 # infinite retries on insert failure
> $ActionQueueSaveOnShutdown on # save in-memory data if rsyslog shuts
> down :syslogtag, isequal, "app2″ :omrelp:192.168.152.3:20514
```